# Ember nested route. Load more models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

### JsBin http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/153/

I know how to load more then one model to a route, using Ember.RSVP.hash. (see Jsbin Children menu).
I use dynamic part to access one elem from a collection `children/1`.
But i cant load more models to a nested resource.

In my example i want to populate all the toys for a select, not just list the toys of the child.

I have tried to access the model of the route `children`

```
App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(param){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({   
      allToys: this.modelFor("children"),
      child:this.store.find('child', param.child_id)
    });

  }
});
```

and use its model's toy property (since there  have already loaded all of the toys)

**child.hbs**

```
<h4>All avaiable toys</h4>
<table>
{{#each toy in model.allToys.toys}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{toy.name}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem here is your attempting to grab the model from `children`, but you haven't defined a `children` route, you defined a `childrenIndex` route.  And if you were to navigate directly to the `child` route the `childrenIndex` route wouldn't be instantiated.  It's only hit when you hit the `children` route and no deeper.  So either you'll need to move the logic from the `childrenIndex` to `children` route, or just use `all` on the store, which doesn't fetch any new data, just returns all of the different types of toys in the store.

```
this.store.all('toy')
```

The secondary problem you have is when you use link-to and send a model, it skips the model hook, which is a problem for dynamic routes (where you define `:id`) and you're expecting it to return multiple models, this is discouraged on this type of route, and recommended that you set up additional properties on the controller in `setupController`

```
App.ChildRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(param){
    this.store.find('child', param.child_id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model); //default implementation of setupController
    controller.set('allToys', this.store.all('toy'));
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/155/edit

#### Serialize

```
serialize: function(model){
  return {child_id:model.get('id')};
}
```

http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/163/edit

Comment: thank you. The 2nd problem is clear, but i dont know how to achive the same system (list and a new page -no outlet- with the details). If i call /children/1 "Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object. " I even tried to flatten the nested routes: http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/159

Comment: that's just an issue with the route, so you have :child_id in the route, and ember by default tries to build the url based on the model, and when it tries to get child_id off of your model it's undefined.  The trick is to tell ember how to get the id off your model, and you can use the serialize hook in the route to do so

Comment: example included above, I had to upgrade the version of ember due to some handlebars issue (not sure what it was, but not worth investigating).  Additionally it doesn't appear to be setting the hasmany relationships properly on find by id `/children/1`

Comment: kingpin2k: "Additionally it doesn't appear to be setting the hasmany relationships properly on find by id /children/1" - maybe my ApplicationSerializer is wrong. I know you wrote; loading multiple models isdiscouraged on this type of route, but i cant find any other way to get this working. here is the new JsBin:http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/166. Maybe someone will find it helpful.